# Need help calculating the density of $(a,b)X$ where $X$ has density $f$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I’m currently working on a problem where I need to calculate the density of $(a,b)X=(aX,bX)$ where $a,b>0$ and $X$ has density $f$ .

However, I’m facing some difficulties as the Jacobian method, which I initially thought to use, is not applicable in my case. According to this [source](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Est309-1/jacobian.pdf),
the Jacobian method cannot be used as my function $h: R \to R^2$ is not applicable.

It’s worth noting that for the one-dimensional case, we have that the density of $aX$ is given by $\frac{1}{a}f(\frac{x}{a})$.

According to the comments below, $(aX,bX)$ has no density. I don't have much background in advanced probability. Could you help me understand the intuition of why density does not exist?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: what means $(a,b)X$ ?

Comment: The vector $(aX,bX)$

Comment: $\mathbb P\{aX\leq x,bX\leq y\}=\mathbb P\{X\geq \min\{\frac{x}{a},\frac{y}{b}\}\}=...$

Comment: $(aX,bX)$ does not have a density

Comment: If there is no density, it's really something I didn't expect. I would like to better understand why. For a moment, I thought it was an easy generalization of the one-dimensional case.

Comment: A random vector has a density if and only if its law is absolutely continuous with respect to lebesgue measure. On the other hand, the graph of any (measurable) function is lebesgue measure zero.